# Loop through Data to Populate Form and Export to individual PDFs

Tags: vba, excel

I posted a question about this recently, but I didn't provide a full scope of what I was trying to do. Thank you to whoever helped me out the first time!

Here is what I'm trying to do.

I'm trying to populate a form with data from another sheet. The code below runs. However, when I look at the folder where the files would be placed in, I only get one file. I should see 4 files as I'm intending with For i = 2 To 5.

[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKcfu.jpg)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqPKF.jpg)

Things to note: 
Data from Column A populates Range("B4:I4") <--- Cell of Name in Form. 
Data from Column B populates Range("B16:I16") <--- Cell of Job Title in Form.

```
Sub FormPop_Export_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim Building_Location As String
Dim dataWS As Worksheet, formWS As Worksheet
Dim thisFile As Range, destRange As Range
Dim thisFile2 As Range, destRange2 As Range


FolderPath = "C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\PAF_Output\"

MkDir FolderPath

Set dataWS = Sheets("Data")
Set formWS = Sheets("Form")
For i = 2 To 5
Set thisFile2 = dataWS.Range("A" & i)
Set destRange2 = formWS.Range("B4:I4")
thisFile2.Copy destRange2

Set thisFile = dataWS.Range("B" & i)
Set destRange = formWS.Range("B16:I16")
thisFile.Copy destRange


If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(formWS.Range("B16:I16"), "Coordinator") = 
destRange.Cells.Count Then
    Building_Location = "East Quad"
Else
    Building_Location = ""
End If
formWS.Range("D14:H14").Value = Building_Location


Sheets(Array("Form")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=FolderPath & thisFile & ".pdf", _
openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False

Next i

MsgBox "All PDF's have been exported to folder."


End Sub
```

May I ask for someone's help with this? I'm ripping my hair out!

Comment: Did you perhaps mean Filename:=FolderPath & thisFile2.Value ?

Comment: @QHarr must be, now I get your answer. `B2:B5` all have the same value so the PDF is getting overwritten each time.

Comment: I'm losing the plot with tiredness myself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to use `thisFile2` in the loop.

```
For i = 2 To 5
        Set thisFile2 = dataWS.Range("A" & i)

         Worksheets("PAF Form").ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FolderPath & thisFile2.Value & ".pdf", _
        openafterpublish:=False, ignoreprintareas:=False

Next
```

As `formWS.Range("B16:I16")`  is a merged then the `Countif` test should actually be `=1` or, as @BigBen points out, simply `If formWS.Range("B16") = "Coordinator" Then "East Quad"`